# Component Not Found (Vuetify & Vuejs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuetify.js

Component not found error. In vuetify 1.5.5 and vue 2.6.12 with vue-template-compiler 2.6.12. I have tried some guys on Discord but they cant seem to figure out what might be the problem here. Sometimes it issues our=t the component not found error, sometimes it doesnt run at all even if both libraries are the same version.
**App.Vue**

```
<template> <v-app>
<v-content>
  <router-view></router-view>
</v-content></v-app>
</template><script>
export default {
name: "App",

components: {},

mounted() {},

data: () => ({}),
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

So the main.js contains mostly imports from javascript and initialization of libraries and modules **main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store/index";
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';
import "./plugins/vuetify";

import 'animate.css'
import './assets/custom.css'
import './assets/table.css'
import './assets/google-like-text.css'
import VeeValidate from "vee-validate";

import VueSession from "vue-session";
import VueGoogleCharts from 'vue-google-charts';


import 'vue-orgchart/dist/style.min.css'

import Snotify from 'vue-snotify'
import 'vue-snotify/styles/material.css';

Vue.use(VeeValidate, { inject: false });


var options = {
 persist: true
};

Vue.use(VueSession, options);
Vue.use(VueGoogleCharts);
Vue.use(Snotify)


Vue.config.productionTip = false;
 new Vue({
 router,
 store,
 render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

And **vuetify.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import colors from "vuetify/es5/util/colors"

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'md',
  theme: {
    primary: "#2E7D32",
    secondary: colors.grey.darken1,
    accent: colors.shades.black,
    error: colors.red.accent3
  }
})
```

[image: d]

Comment: please share the code of `app.js` and `App.vue`

Comment: Can a share your code?

Comment: Pls add the code in your question

Comment: Check the updates i ave made to the code @Amaarrockz

Comment: please share `vuetify.js` file

Comment: Done adding vuetify.js